# Why is one construction incorrect in this sentence?

Tags: errors

Archaeological evidence shows that Viking ships were lighter, slimmer, and faster than `that of the English` **vs**  `those used by the English`?

Why is the first underlined form incorrect while the second is correct? Which grammar rule does the first violate?

Comment: It seems like they're trying to confuse you with that question: *those used by the English* and *those of the English* are both correct, while *that of the English* and *that used by the English* are both wrong. So they're changing two things, but only one of these makes the sentence ungrammatical. And furthermore, I don't like the correct sentence because it's not as parallel as it might be ... it would be better to say *"ships used by the Vikings ... ships used by the English"* or *"Viking ships ... those of the English"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The antecedent of the word after "than," is "ships," plural.  So the plural "those" would be preferred under the rule that the referring and referred to agree in number.

Answer (score 2):

> Archaeological evidence shows that Viking ships were lighter, slimmer,
>   and faster than that of the English

would be correct if we assume that the *English had only one boat* (**that** boat/**those** boats). It's highly unlikely that there was only one English boat against the Viking fleet.